# How to efficiently query element at index

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

There is a DOM structure like:

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="another-container">
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="another-container">
    <div class="another-another-container">
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to select the third `.item`, ignoring other elements (such as containers).

So I do:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.item')[2].dataset.isSelected = true;
```

Which works.

But the DOM structure can be large and this method might be called frequently. Querying all elements (`document.querySelectorAll('.item')`) to get just one seems not efficient.

- Is there any way to optimize this code? (besides converting list of `.item` to a static array)
- Or is `querySelectorAll` dynamic by nature and it does not actually fetch all DOM elements?

Comment: How about `document.getElementById('container').childNodes[2]`

Comment: @brk, I need to query `.item`, not child element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, unless you're dealing with an enormous data set, you should be fine using `document.querySelectorAll()` and finding the index you need with the returned nodelist.

I made an obnoxious [CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/xhynk/pen/XQxMvX?editors=1111) here that's like 10,000 lines of divs, and it can cycle through a simple function that turns a random non-cached index red (similar to your example). I feel like you may be succumbing to "Premature Optimization".

Be sure to open up the console on that pen, I set the interval to 0.01ms, and it seems to have no trouble digging through that nodelist for random indices which could be in the thousands. So calling it and digging for the 3rd every time would probably be even faster.